# Difference between two dates #

Tags: c#, datetime, date-difference

I have to calculate number of days difference between today and SubmittedDate, but if I the SubmittedDate = today
my Result = 0,430090... Instead of 1

here is my code:

```
 DaysDiff = (today.Subtract(DataUtilities.GetSafeDateTime(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.SUBMITTEDDATE_FIELD]))).TotalDays,
```

could you please help me ?

Comment: If the two dates contains also the time the result could be less than 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`TotalDays`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays(v=vs.110).aspx) property is a double. It also takes the hours and minutes in account, so that might cause the subtraction of two days get fractions too.

If you want to round that, you could use `Math.Round`,  `Math.Ceiling` or `Math.Floor` depending on your needs. Taking your expected outcome, I guess you need to use `Ceiling`:

```
double ceiledDays = Math.Ceiling(ts.TotalDays);
```

Or you could get the `Date` part of the two dates and calculate with that.